# The spring annotation of Date that makes sure the value is the max time of the date

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc, annotations

Please, let me know how to make it sure that it's maximum value of java.tuil.Date type, as using spring framework annotation.

What annotations should I add to the value "date" field?

[HTML part]

```
<form ...>
    <input type="text" name="date" value="2017-09-29"/>
</form>
```

[JAVA part]

```
Public class myClass {
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="YYYY-MM-DD")
    private Date date; //want to make it the maximum value of the date "2017-09-29" eg.2017-09-29 23:59:59
    public Date getDate() {
        return this.date;
    }
    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and 1. use the java.time classes, not the old, ugly Date class; 2. don't represent the end of a day by "day at 23:59:59" (what about milliseconds, BTW), but by "next day at 00:00:00". Or, if youonly care about days anyway, by using LocalDates instead of instants.

Comment: What I meant was how to set the end of day. My English is not good enough to express exact my intention so I just used the example. Unfortunately I didn’t get what I want ‘cause of my poor English. Anyways thank you for your advice.